# Flutter - Get Android device name

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am implementing an app using `Flutter` and I want to get the device name, i.e. X's Huawei phone, using `device_info` package.

I could get it in `iOS` using this code:

```
IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
print('device name ${iosDeviceInfo.name}');
```

But in `Android`, I couldn't get the name. I can get many other values like the model, brand and display.

Is there a parameter in this package or another package that I can get `Android` device's name from it?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I implemented, only tested for android and iOS. Essentially, iOS uses name, while Android uses manufacturer and model. In most cases I believe you can replace brand for manufacturer, I didn't have a lot of test devices, do your own research.

```
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

String getDeviceName(){
    Map deviceInfo = (await DeviceInfoPlugin().deviceInfo).data;
    String? brand = deviceInfo['brand'];
    String? model = deviceInfo['model'];
    String? name = deviceInfo['name'];

    return name ?? '$manufacturer $model';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is already quite old I would like to provider some information for devs asking this question in 2024.

I developed the package [device_marketing_names](https://pub.dev/packages/device_marketing_names) which loads device marketing names, so the names users probably know, not the cryptic ones given to Android devices internally.
The package supports Android and iOS (updated regularly, mostly monthly, with new datasets) and also the web.

**Add the dependency in your pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  device_marketing_names: ^0.8.0
```

**Use it**

```
final deviceNames = DeviceMarketingNames();

// Get one marketing name of the device.
final singleDeviceName = await deviceMarketingNames.getSingleName();

// Get all marketing names of the device.
final deviceNames = await deviceMarketingNames.getNames();

// Get one marketing name for the given model.
final singleDeviceNameFromModel = deviceNames.getSingleNameFromModel(DeviceType.android, "ONEPLUS A5010");

// Get all marketing names for the given model.
final deviceNamesFromModel = deviceNames.getNamesFromModel(DeviceType.android, "ONEPLUS A5010");
```

Disclaimer: As already mentioned, I developed the package, so I'm probably biased in regards to the usefulness and quality of the package.

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings.Global.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME)
```

Returns the name that was given to the device via device settings. Only available on Android 7.1+ (N_MR1).
This name is seen when connecting to Bluetooth or wifi network. Using platform channels I delegated this name to Flutter side:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)
private fun getDeviceName(): String {
    return Settings.Global.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME)
}
```

And then just call this method using PlatformChannels via Flutter.

Answer (score -1):

You can get Android device's name from board:

```
if(Platform.isAndroid){
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
  return androidInfo.board;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) package provides getting Android and iOS device info. It doesn't support any other platform as of now.

```
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Running on ${androidInfo.model}');  // e.g. "Moto G (4)"

IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
print('Running on ${iosInfo.utsname.machine}');  // e.g. "iPod7,1"
```